# Survey answer to be counted in array

Tags: vb.net-2010

I count how many students answering survey Question1 to Question17.

- Q1 to Q15 is Likeness questions (*strongly disagree / disagree / agree / strongly agree*)
- Q16 is a *Yes / No* question: `Do you go to the lab?`
- If students answer *Yes* (=2) then Q17 is the likeness question. If Q16 is *No* (=1) then skip Q17

I am able to count from Q1 to Q15 as showed in the codes below, but I am not able to deal with Q16 (y/n). The output requires to show Q1-Q15, skip Q16 and show Q17.
I also have an another table, `tblSurveyQuestion(questID, questType, question)`. At Q16, the questID=Survey16, questType="Y".

Can you please show me how to insert the code to deal with Q16? My code so far:

```
    'assume dt is a datatable that is declared and the connection works
    Dim ans(16, 3) As Integer      '17 questions with Q16 is a y/n question  
    For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        If dt.Rows(I).Item(2) = 1 Then
            Dim Answer1() As String = dt.Rows(I).Item(3).Split(";")  
            For j1 As Integer = 0 To 16     
                Dim k1 As Integer = (Val(Answer1(j1)))
                ans(j1, k1 - 1) += 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Where or how do you show the Questions later? Do you use the `ans` array? You probably also need to look at your counter `j1` (if the question result are counted by `j1`): either when evaluation the result, or later when showing the answers.

Comment: I declare a datatable, add column and row to a dataset to display them on the VS2010/Wins Form/ReportViewer report. The codes above works only for q1-q15. However, when I encounter q17 (I can skip q16 b/c I only need values in q17), I get error b/c q17 either likeness question or 0 (N/A). If q17=0, ans(j1, k1-1) = ans(-1) => error! Help!

Comment: Can you post an example of the string that you are spliting to retrieve the answers (the string that holds all answer, right)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are evaluation the answers sequentially and you want to have knowledge of a previous data at some point, you need to know in your code which question are you evaluating (or showing) currently in order to act accordingly.

You already have the evaluated anser of Question 16 in `ans(15)`, so you just need to check if you are at index 16 (=Question17) or not and handle the result of `ans(15)`. One possibility would be to use:

- `if / elseif / else / end if`
- or a [Select..Case statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

You need to:

- declare a variable to store the result of the evaluation of Question16
- when evaluation Question17 check the stored result of Question16
- act accordingly (for example not saving Question17 or not showing it)

A very simple solution could look like this:

```
'assume dt is a datatable that is declared and the connection works
Dim ans(16, 3) As Integer      '17 questions with Q16 is a y/n question  
For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    If dt.Rows(I).Item(2) = 1 Then
        Dim Answer1() As String = dt.Rows(I).Item(3).Split(";")
        'declare a store for the answer of question 16
        Dim answer16IsPositive as Boolean = False
        For j1 As Integer = 0 To 16
            Dim k1 As Integer = (Val(Answer1(j1)))
            ans(j1, k1 - 1) += 1
            If (j1 = 15) ' we are at the 16th answer
                If (k1 = 1) 'save result of answer 16!
                    answer16IsPositive = True
                End If
            End If
            If (j1 = 16) ' we are at the 17th answer
                If (Not answer16IsPositive)
                    ' deal with answer 17!
                'Else
                ' do nothing
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, pasty. But when I debug it, I encounter an error: When j1=15 then the flag is set to True. Then it skips j1=16 go to next of the inside for loop, j1=16, Answer1(16)=0; therefore, k1=0. If k1=0 then ans(16, -1) popping up an error. Can you please modify your code?
BTW, sorry I forgot to tell you that q17 has the likeness answer OR 0 (not applicable)

Comment: You could take my code as reference and modify it to meet your needs. Maybe if you just reverse the if condition(`k1 <> 1`) it will work?